# How to convert date and time object 12 hours format?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetimeformatter

I get date and time from client in the controller, here the signature of the function:

```
  public ResponseEntity<Meeting> create(@RequestParam(name = "start") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime start)
```

if I print the start variable it shows date and time in 24-hour format:

```
2020-12-10T16:52:42.014982500
```

But I want the value of the LocalDateTime variable will be in 12 hours format, so I tried to change DateTimeFromat in the function's signature

```
    public ResponseEntity<Meeting> create(@RequestParam(name = "start") @DateTimeFormat(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh.mm aa")) LocalDateTime start).3
```

But on this row:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh.mm aa")
```

I get error:

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

My question is what params @DateTimeFormat have to get so it can convert date and time from client to 12 hours format?

Comment: It's unclear why you tried `@DateTimeFormat(DateTimeFormatter.ofPatte...)`. Spring's `DateTimeFormat` annotation is not related to the `java.time` types. And it's an annotation, so all of its elements expect constant expressions.

Comment: Savior thank you for post.I need to convert date and time to 12 hours format thats all...sorry for complicated the thigs...any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A date-time object does not store the formatting information. A `LocalDateTime` is supposed to store just the date and time components (i.e. year, month, day of the month, hour, minute, second and the fraction of second). When you print an object of `LocalDateTime`, you get what its `toString` function returns. If you need the value in a different format, you need to get a formatted string out of this object but ***in no case, you will be able to store the format into the instance of `LocalDateTime`***.

Given below is a simple demo:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-10T16:52:42.014982500";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu hh.mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(ldt);// Prints the value of ldt#toString

        // Get a formatted string
        String formatted = ldt.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-10T16:52:42.014982500
10/12/2020 04.52 PM
```

### Update

From your comment on the other answer (which has been deleted now), I learnt that your date-time string is `2020-12-08T21:34:18.119+00:00` which has a zone offset information (`+00:00`) and therefore, the most appropriate type would be `OffsetDateTime`.

Change the annotation as

```
public ResponseEntity<Meeting> create(@RequestParam(name = "start") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME) OffsetDateTime start)
```

or

```
public ResponseEntity<Meeting> create(@RequestParam(name = "start") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) OffsetDateTime start)
```

Check the [Spring documentation page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE_TIME) to learn more about the second option.

**A quick demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-12-08T21:34:18.119+00:00");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-08T21:34:18.119Z
```